# Bootstrap parameter estimate of non-linear optimization in R: Why is it different than the regular parameter estimate?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, nonlinear-optimization, statistics-bootstrap

Here's the short version of my question. The code is below.

I calculated the parameters for the non-linear von Bertalanffy growth equation in R using optim(), and now I am trying to add 95% confidence intervals to the von B growth coefficient K by bootstrapping. For at least one of the years of data, when I summarize the bootstrapped output of the growth coefficient K, the mean and median parameter estimates from bootstrapping are quite different than the estimated parameter:

```
>summary(temp.store) # summary of bootstrap values
     Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max.
 0.002449 0.005777 0.010290 0.011700 0.016970 0.056720

> est.K [1] 0.01655956  # point-estimate from the optimization
```

I suspect the discrepancy is because there are errors in the bootstrap of the random draw that bias the result, although I have used try() to stop the optimization from crashing when there is a combination of input values that cause an error. So I would like to know what to do to fix that issue. I think I'm doing things correctly, because the fitted curve looks right.

Also, I have run this code for data from other years, and in at least one other year, the bootrap estimate and the regular estimate are very close.

Long-winded version:

The von Bertalanffy growth curve (VBGC) for length is given by:
L(t) = L.inf * [1 - exp(-K*(t-t0))] (Eq. 3.1.0.1, from [FAO](http://www.fao.org/docrep/W5449e/w5449e05.htm#3.1%20the%20von%20bertalanffy%20growth%20equation))

where L(t) is the fish's length, L.inf is the asymptotic maximum length, K is the growth coefficient, t is the time step and t0 is when growth began. L(t) and t are the observed data. Usually time or age is measured in years, but here I am looking at juvenile fish data and I have made t the day the of year ("doy") starting with January 1 = 1.

To estimate the starting parameters for the optimization, I have used a linearization of the VBGC equation.

```
doy <- c(156,205,228,276,319,380)
len <- c(36,56,60,68,68,71)
data06 <- data.frame(doy,len)
```

Function to get starting parameters for the optimization:

```
get.init <-function(dframe){ # linearization of the von B
  l.inf <- 80  # by eyeballing max juvenile fish
  # make a response variable and store it in the data frame:
  # Eqn. 3.3.3.1 in FAO document
  dframe$vonb.y <- - log(1 - (dframe$len)/l.inf  )
  lin.vonb <- lm(vonb.y ~ doy, data=dframe)
  icept <- lin.vonb$coef[1] #  0.01534013 # intercept is a
  slope <-  k.lin <- lin.vonb$coef[2] # slope is the K param
  t0 <- - icept/slope # get t0 from this relship: intercept= -K * t0
  pars <- c(l.inf,as.numeric(slope),as.numeric(t0))
}
```

Sums of squares for von Bertalanffy growth equation

```
vbl.ssq <- function(theta, data){
  linf=theta[1]; k=theta[2]; t0=theta[3]
  # name variables for ease of use
  obs.length=data$len
  age=data$doy
  #von B equation
  pred.length=linf*(1-exp(-k*(age-t0)))
  #sums of squares
  ssq=sum((obs.length-pred.length)^2)
}
```

Estimate parameters

```
#Get starting parameter values
theta_init <- get.init(dframe=data06)
# optimize VBGC by minimizing sums of square differences
len.fit <- optim(par=theta_init, fn=vbl.ssq, method="BFGS", data=data06)

est.linf <- len.fit$par[1] # vonB len-infinite
est.K <- len.fit$par[2]      # vonB K
est.t0 <- len.fit$par[3]     # vonB t0
```

Bootstrapping

```
# set up for bootstrap loop
tmp.frame <- data.frame()
temp.store <- vector()

# bootstrap to get 95% conf ints on growth coef K
for (j in 1:1000){
  # choose indices at random, with replacement
  indices <- sample(1:length(data06[,1]),replace=T)
  # values from original data corresponding to those indices
  new.len <- data06$len[indices]
  new.doy <- data06$doy[indices]
  tmp.frame <- data.frame(new.doy,new.len)
  colnames(tmp.frame) <- c("doy","len")

  init.par <- get.init(tmp.frame)
  # now get the vonB params for the randomly selected samples
  # using try() to keep optimizing errors from crashing the program
  try(  len.fit.bs <- optim(par=init.par, fn=vbl.ssq, method="BFGS", data=tmp.frame))
  tmp.k <- len.fit.bs$par[2]
  temp.store[j] <- tmp.k
}
```

95% confidence interval for K parameter

```
k.ci <- quantile(temp.store,c(0.025,0.975))
#       2.5%       97.5% 
#0.004437702 0.019784178
```

Here's the problem:

```
#>summary(temp.store)
#     Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max.
# 0.002449 0.005777 0.010290 0.011700 0.016970 0.056720
# 
# est.K [1] 0.01655956
```

Example of error:

```
Error in optim(par = init.par, fn = vbl.ssq, method = "BFGS", data = tmp.frame) : 
  non-finite finite-difference value [2]
```

I don't believe I am making any errors with the optimization because the VBGC fit looks reasonable. Here are the plots:

```
plot(x=data06$doy,y=data06$len,xlim=c(0,550),ylim=c(0,100))
legend(x="topleft",legend=paste("Length curve 2006"), bty="n")
curve(est.linf*(1-exp(-est.K*(x-est.t0))), add=T,type="l")

plot(x=2006,y=est.K, main="von B growth coefficient for length; 95% CIs",
    ylim=c(0,0.025))
arrows(x0=2006,y0=k.ci[1],x1=2006,y1=k.ci[2], code=3,
    angle=90,length=0.1)
```

[image]
[image: K parameter estimate with the bootstrapped confidence intervals]

Comment: You are making this too difficult. Use nls with this selfstarting model: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/SSasympOff.html Then you can use the nlsBoot function in the nlstools package.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that! Do you think that will also solve the problem of different point estimates and median or median bootstrap estimates?

Comment: I can't study your code in detail since I'm on my phone. It doesn't look like you are bootstrapping the residuals which is what you should do because it preserves the distribution of x values. nlsBoot bootstraps the residuals.

Comment: @Roland, I'm working from Crawley's bootstrapping/confidence intervals example (The R Book, pp.682-3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have a very small number of values, possibly too few to trust the bootstrap method. Then a high proportion of fits fails for the classic bootstrap, because due to the resampling you often have not enough distinct x values.

Here is an implementation using `nls` with a selfstarting model and the boot package.

```
doy <- c(156,205,228,276,319,380)
len <- c(36,56,60,68,68,71)
data06 <- data.frame(doy,len)

plot(len ~ doy, data = data06)

fit <- nls(len ~ SSasympOff(doy, Asym, lrc, c0), data = data06)
summary(fit)
#profiling CI
proCI <- confint(fit)
#          2.5%      97.5%
#Asym 68.290477  75.922174
#lrc  -4.453895  -3.779994
#c0   94.777335 126.112523

curve(predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(doy = x)), add = TRUE)
```

[image: plot of data and predictions]

```
#classic bootstrap
library(boot)
set.seed(42)
boot1 <- boot(data06, function(DF, i) {
  tryCatch(coef(nls(len ~ SSasympOff(doy, Asym, lrc, c0), data = DF[i,])),
           error = function(e) c(Asym = NA, lrc = NA, c0 = NA))
}, R = 1e3)

#proportion of unsuccessful fits
mean(is.na(boot1$t[, 1]))
#[1] 0.256

#bootstrap CI
boot1CI <- apply(boot1$t, 2, quantile, probs = c(0.025, 0.5, 0.975), na.rm = TRUE)
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#2.5%  69.70360 -4.562608  67.60152
#50%   71.56527 -4.100148 113.9287
#97.5% 74.79921 -3.697461 151.03541


#bootstrap of the residuals
data06$res <- residuals(fit)
data06$fit <- fitted(fit)

set.seed(42)
boot2 <- boot(data06, function(DF, i) {
  DF$lenboot <- DF$fit + DF[i, "res"]
  tryCatch(coef(nls(lenboot ~ SSasympOff(doy, Asym, lrc, c0), data = DF)),
           error = function(e) c(Asym = NA, lrc = NA, c0 = NA))
}, R = 1e3)

#proportion of unsuccessful fits
mean(is.na(boot2$t[, 1]))
#[1] 0

#(residuals) bootstrap CI
boot2CI <- apply(boot2$t, 2, quantile, probs = c(0.025, 0.5, 0.975), na.rm = TRUE)
#          [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
#2.5%  70.19380 -4.255165 106.3136
#50%   71.56527 -4.100148 113.9287
#97.5% 73.37461 -3.969012 119.2380
proCI[2,1]

CIs_k <- data.frame(lwr = c(exp(proCI[2, 1]),
                            exp(boot1CI[1, 2]),
                            exp(boot2CI[1, 2])),
                    upr = c(exp(proCI[2, 2]),
                            exp(boot1CI[3, 2]),
                            exp(boot2CI[3, 2])),
                    med = c(NA,
                            exp(boot1CI[2, 2]),
                            exp(boot2CI[2, 2])),
                    estimate = exp(coef(fit)[2]),
                    method = c("profile", "boot", "boot res"))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(CIs_k, aes(y = estimate, ymin = lwr, ymax = upr, x = method)) +
  geom_errorbar() +
  geom_point(aes(color = "estimate"), size = 5) +
  geom_point(aes(y = med, color = "boot median"), size = 5) +
  ylab("k") + xlab("") +
  scale_color_brewer(name = "", type = "qual", palette = 2) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 22)
```

[image: resulting plot]

As you see, the bootstrap CI is wider than the profile CI and bootstrapping the residuals results in a more narrow estimated CI. All of them are almost symmetric. Furthermore, the medians are close to the point estimates.

As a first step of investigating what goes wrong in your code, you should look at the proportion of failed fits from your procedure.

Comment: That's hugely helpful. I was also wondering why the bootstrap confidence intervals the way I was doing it were not at all symmetrical around the point estimates (9 years of growth data).

Comment: one more question if I'm allowed. I sometimes optimize non-linear fits using different methods, nls(), and optim() minimizing the sums of squares and the negative log likelihood, then take the best fit according to AICc. Can I dispense with using the multiple methods and just go with nls()? It usually gives me the best parameters according to AICc anyway (but not always). (The editor is not letting me use @Roland)

Comment: Depending on the models you are fitting it might be prudent to try different optimizers. The optimx package is great for that. However, you only need to check the SSE.